# Nested types inside a protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

It is possible to have nested types declared inside protocols, like this:

```
protocol Nested {

    class NameOfClass {
        var property: String { get set }
    }
}
```

Xcode says **"Type not allowed here"**:

> Type 'NameOfClass' cannot be nested in protocol 'Nested'

I want to create a protocol that needs to have a nested type. Is this not possible or I can do this in another other way?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A protocol cannot require a nested type, but it can require an associated type that conforms to another protocol. An implementation could use either a nested type or a type alias to meet this requirement.

```
protocol Inner {
    var property: String { get set }
}
protocol Outer {
    associatedtype Nested: Inner
}

class MyClass: Outer {
    struct Nested: Inner {
        var property: String = ""
    }
}

struct NotNested: Inner {
    var property: String = ""
}
class MyOtherClass: Outer {
    typealias Nested = NotNested
}
```

Comment: Cool, but not understand one thing! What the code typealias Nested = NotNested mean?

Comment: It creates a type alias to meet the requirements of `Outer`. There is now a new name for `NotNested` as if it were nested within `MyOtherClass`.
If `Outer` declared any uses of `Nested`, this could probably be inferred by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can have instance/type properties inside of a protocol that conform to another protocol:

```
public protocol InnerProtocol {
    static var staticText: String {get}
    var text: String {get}
}

public protocol OuterProtocol {
    static var staticInner: InnerProtocol.Type {get}
    var inner: InnerProtocol {get}
}

public struct MyStruct: OuterProtocol {
    public static var staticInner: InnerProtocol.Type = Inner.self
    public var inner: InnerProtocol = Inner()

    private struct Inner: InnerProtocol {
        public static var staticText: String {
            return "inner static text"
        }
        public var text = "inner text"
    }
}

// for instance properties
let mystruct = MyStruct()
print(mystruct.inner.text)

// for type properties
let mystruct2: MyStruct.Type = MyStruct.self
print(mystruct2.staticInner.staticText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code, but in a way that works:

```swift
protocol Nested {
    associatedtype NameOfClass: HasStringProperty

}
protocol HasStringProperty {
    var property: String { get set }
}
```

And you can use it like this

```
class Test: Nested {
    class NameOfClass: HasStringProperty {
        var property: String = "Something"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!