# Using CodingKeys with custom protocol

Tags: swift, enums, protocols, codable

I have the following Codable protocol containing a variable which I would like to exclude from the codable ones.

Problem is that I can't use the CodingKeys enum made for that within my own protocol: `Type 'CodingKeys' cannot be nested in protocol 'Animal'`.

```
protocol Animal: Codable {

    var name: String { get set }
    var color: String { get }

    var selfiePicture: Selfie { get }

    // Not possible
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case color
    }

}
```

How could I resolve this?

---

**EDIT with more code and more specific example**

`Animal` is used by several structs (can't be classes):

```
struct Frog: Animal {
    var name: String
    var color: String

    // extra variables on top of Animal's ones
    var isPoisonous: Bool

    var selfiePicture = [...]
}
```

It is also used as a variable array on another top-codable object:

```
final class Farm: Codable {

    var address: String
    // more variables
    var animals: [Animal]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case address
        case animals
    }

    convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        address = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .address)
        animals = try values.decode([Animal].self, forKey: .animals)   // ERROR --> Protocol 'Animal' as a type cannot conform to 'Decodable'
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look here for nested types in protocols: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845066/nested-types-inside-a-protocol

Comment: You can share the keys if you use a `class` and implement `Codable` manually. then any other classes that share can inherit the `class` with the keys

Comment: @Iorem I can't since `MyProtocol` is used by structs and not classes.

Comment: I edited my question for more precisions.

Comment: You don't need a protocol, use `struct Animal` and add a property `type` that could be an enum of all your types of animals

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'd love to but `Animal` "sub-struct" have their own variables on top of the `Animal` ones (cf. `isPoisonous` from `struct Frog`). That's why I choose `protocol` here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48819953/alternate-approach-to-inheritance-for-swift-structs).

Comment: Ok I understand. Are the extra properties also Codable?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes. I can just add 1 variable per Animal struct type into my `Farm` object, but I was expecting a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Sorry but I don’t understand that last comment

Comment: Yes @JoakimDanielson, I need the extra properties from `Frog` to be Codable as well. I just saw your answer was edited. I am taking a look at it now, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is to use composition, move the common properties to a new type and use that type in the protocol.

So let's make a type for the common properties and let that type hold the `CodingKey` enum

```
struct AnimalCommon: Codable {
    var name: String
    var color: String

    var selfiePicture: Selfie = Selfie()

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case color
    }
}
```

And the protocol becomes

```
protocol Animal: Codable {
    var common: AnimalCommon { get set }
}
```

After that it will be quite easy to implement the actual Animal types, for example

```
struct Frog: Animal {
    var common: AnimalCommon
    var isPoisonous: Bool
}

let frog = Frog(common: AnimalCommon(name: "kermit", color: "green"), isPoisonous: false)
do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(frog)

    if let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) { print(frog) }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

You can also add an extension to the protocol with computed properties so you can access the properties directly, i.e `frog.name = "Kermit"`

```
extension Animal {
    var name: String {
        get {
            common.name
        }
        set {
            common.name = newValue
        }
    }

    var color: String {
        common.color
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is that I use the MyProtocol from another final class containing `var protocolStructs: [MyProtocol]`, which needs MyProtocol to be `Codable`.

Comment: @Tulleb But MyProtocol is conforming to `Codable`

Comment: I have the error `Protocol 'MyProtocol' as a type cannot conform to 'Decodable'` when decoding `protocolStructs`. I'll edit my question with more informations.

Comment: Thank you for your edit @JoakimDanielson, I'm trying it now. It looks great!

Comment: Looks like Swift does not want to decode protocols: I still have the `Protocol 'Animal' as a type cannot conform to 'Decodable'` error (line `animals = try values.decode([Animal].self, forKey: .animals)`).

Comment: I just saw this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57026463/protocol-type-cannot-conform-to-protocol-because-only-concrete-types-can-conform. I'll try to replace the `protocol` with some kind of `enum` and keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Protocol type cannot conform to protocol because only concrete types can conform to protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57026463/protocol-type-cannot-conform-to-protocol-because-only-concrete-types-can-conform), I had to give up on the `protocol` and use a `struct` + `enum` inside instead.

Even though @JoakimDanielson's answer was promising, it does not fix an error I have while trying to decode the `Animal` array from my `Farm` class: `Protocol 'Animal' as a type cannot conform to 'Decodable'`.

Here is how my model looks like at the end:

```
struct Animal: Codable {

    enum Species: Codable {
        case frog(FrogSpecificities)
        case ...

        var selfiePicture: Selfie {
            switch self {
            case .frog(let frogSpecificities):
                return frogSpecificities.selfie
            case ...
                ...
            }
        }

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case FrogSpecificities
            case ...
        }

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

            if let frogSpecificities = try? values.decode(FrogSpecificities.self, forKey: .frogSpecificities) {
                self = .frog(frogSpecificities)
            } else if ...
                ...
            } else {
                // throw an error here if no case was decodable
            }
        }

        func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
            var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

            switch self {
            case .frog(let frogSpecificities):
                try container.encode(frogSpecificities, forKey: .frogSpecificities)
            case ...:
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    var name: String
    let color: String

    var species: Species

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case color
        case specificities
    }

}

struct FrogSpecificities: Codable {

    let isPoisonous: Bool
    let selfie = Selfie()

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isPoisonous
    }

}

final class Farm: Codable {

    var address: String
    var animals: [Animal]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case address
        case animals
    }

    convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        address = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .address)
        animals = try values.decode([Animal].self, forKey: .animals) // Works fine
    }
}
```

My `Farm` object can now contains an `Animal` arrays with specific codable `struct` for each one of them. It can also contains variables which are not codable.
I can access each specificities of my animals like this:

```
if let firstAnimel = MyFarm.animals.firstObject,
    case .frog(let frogSpecificities) = firstAnimal.species {
    print(frogSpecificities.isPoisonous)
}
```